# PacketTrace Default Gateway

Tags: cisco-ios

I've set up the default gateway of the router I am configurating as serial2/0 as they call it on packet trace with the address of 172.16.68.1. When I try and ping the gateway from the pc with the address 172.16.16.1 I just get an error saying request timed out.

Have I done the default gateway correctly and if I have can anyone suggest what is causing the time out?

Comment: What is the subnet on the PC and *its* default gateway?

Comment: The subnet on the pc is 255.255.248.0 and the default gateway is 172.16.68.1 but I'm not sure if that is right as I have to assign it myself. Should it be the serial port as the default gateway as that's the DTE

Answer (score 0):

The subnet `172.16.16.1/21` which includes the PC does not contain the IP of its default gateway (172.16.68.1). That means that the PC cannot access its own default gateway with its current routing table.

You need to either setup a router/gateway within the PC's current subnet, or change the subnet settings to include the gateway. Keep in mind that the last alternative might not be applicable in your network.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. The gateway was correct it was the DTE and the DCE that was messed up on my end and causing problems with the pinging as I can now ping it with no problems. Thank you for all your help :)